# Can I undo a git reflog?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch on Github. I merged a change that I didn't want to merge.

I've been trying to undo that commit. I did `git reset --hard` and `git reset <commit id>`.

I kept getting the error `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.`

I read on a stack overflow post that I should try `git reflog.`

But, now, my branch has 100 commits instead of 8 commits. It took all the other work that I was doing over the weekend on a similar part of the code and added those changes to the same branch.

How do I undo that and make those commits no longer associated with this branch?

Comment: The error you are reporting is not when you reset but when you try to push to another repo, right?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you've done. It appears you've brought in changes that aren't needed. `git reset --hard` would remove all uncommited changes, you'd be left at the state of the remote. `git reset <commit id>` would rewind back. Now you would be *behind* your remote, hence why you cannot push. `git reflog` allows you to restore missing objects but I really don't know how you've used it.

Comment: These are commits that I did push but on a different branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that the branch you have reset has the correct commits:

```
git log
```

If not, [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is there to list all the tips of branches and other references that were updated in the local repository. 
Find the one for your branch, before the "bad" merge: reset to that.

```
# assuming you don't have any work in progress
git reset --hard <good_commit>
```

Then, if the branch is correct locally, and has been reset, you will need to force push it: `git push --force` (assuming you are alone working on that branch, or you would need to notify others first)

Comment: I ran git log and the first result shows the two branches combining into one branch. It says `commit <long_hash> (HEAD -> <first_branch>, <second_branch>)` and underneath it says "Merge branch '<master_branch> into <second_branch>". Just to be super clear because it's all obsfuscated, I want the first branch but not the second branch.

Comment: @Cauder the first commit which would reference the second branch only, *before* the Merge branch, would be the one of interest for you.